# n points on circle how many different strings that dont cross each other?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

n points on circle how many different strings that dont cross each other?

My solution is: $C(n,2)$ which makes total sense, for me. and I know it's not enough. I think it is$ C(n,2) + C(n-1,2)$ because from the point of the first string, it has n-1 points left to choose. but there's a problem because from that points that do cross each other in that selected point. so I believe I'm wrong in the solution. can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you be a little more concise with the statement of the problem? Are you asking for the maximal number of non-intersecting strings? If 2 strings start from the same point are they considered intersecting?

Comment: By meet do you mean meet in the interior of the circle?  To get a reasonably simple answer we will need to assume that the points are in "general" position, meaning there is no point in the interior of the circle through which more than $2$ strings pass. And we need to make it clear exactly what we are counting. By the way, there are $\binom{n}{4}$ intersection points in the interior of the circle.

Comment: @user53970 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557034/every-two-strings-that-dont-cross-each-other-on-a-circle

Comment: @AndréNicolas http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557034/every-two-strings-that-dont-cross-each-other-on-a-circle