# Every two Strings that don't cross each other on a circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

here a picture of a circle with n points on it.
[image]

I need to count how many two strings "groups" on that circle, don't cross each other. to be more precise, "every two strings, need NOT to cross each other.." im bad at english, sorry.

Btw, on my opinion:$ C(n,4)$ is the first part of the answer. (like you see on the picture, we took a set of 4 points of n, but it is also the number of squares that you can build - to be more precise, convex squares, which means the answer for this question is slighly different) or some sort of $C(n,2) + 'something'$

But I believe I need to add something here. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: What does "don't cross each other" mean? Take the two strings $AB$ and $AC$, where $A,B,C$ are distinct. Do these cross? Under one interpretation they cross at $A$. Under another they don't. And a minor question, by two string pair do you mean ordered pair or unordered pair?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I believe that they don't cross each other if they go from A. even if it is the same point. what is the answer if they dont cross A and what is the answer if they can cross A? and i don't know about your question. it says just how many "two strings". i think $C(n,2) + C(n-1,2)$  what is your opinion? it is assumed that they can cross A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume the points are in general position. It is not clear whether by two-string pairs you mean ordered pairs or unordered. We use unordered.

We interpret "don't cross" as meaning that the pair don't cross in the *interior* of the circle. So if $A,B,C$ are distinct points, then we say that $AB$ and $AC$ don't cross.

Take $4$ distinct points on the circle. These determine $3$ unordered pairs of strings, of which $2$ pairs do not meet in the interior of the circle.

Thus the probability two unordered pairs don't cross is $\frac{2}{3}$.  There are $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\binom{n}{2}\cdot \binom{n-2}{2}$ unordered pairs of strings. For the number that don't cross, multiply by $\frac{2}{3}$.

If we consider $AB$ and $AC$ as crossing, multiply by $\frac{1}{3}$ instead of $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: btw, why we multiply it by $1/2$?

Comment: Ir is a matter of interpretation. I am counting the number of *unordered pairs* of (distinct) strings that don't cross. There are $\binom{n}{2}\cdot\binom{n-2}{2}$ **ordered** pairs of strings, I divided by $2$ for unordered.  If you want to count ordered pairs, don't divide by $2$.

Comment: What if they cannot intersect even in point A, what will be the answer then?

Comment: The answer to that is in the last line of the answer: multiply by $1/3$ instead of $2/3$.